# how can I clear the locale in the flutter locale Provider

Tags: flutter, locale, provider

for the internationalization of my app, I'm trying to use the locale provider for the manual user language choice.
But with the part where  I want to reset the language, I struggle some difficulties.
The locale provider doesn't show any problems when I use this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:esosba_app/l10n/l10n.dart';
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
 Locale _locale;
  LocaleProvider(this._locale);//constructor for field initialization

   Locale get locale => _locale;
  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale))return;
    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void clearLocale(){
   

    _locale=  const Locale('en');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

but when I call it in the main file this error appears:
1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

so I tried the following code:

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Locale _locale;

  Locale get locale => _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearLocale() {
    _locale = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

with the result, that no errors appeared when I call it, but the locale provider shows the following errors:

Non-nullable instance field '_locale' must be initialized.
A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Locale'.

how can I fix that problem?
I m gratefully looking forward to your answers :-)
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

So in the end after 2 days of research, I found out, that the nullability of the Locale was possible for older flutter versions, but to make debugging more comfortable, they changed that. If you want to set the Locale to null, you have to use a ? after Locale like so:

```
    class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
    Locale? _locale;

    Locale? get locale => _locale;

    void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;

    _locale = locale;
    notifyListeners();
    }

    void clearLocale() {
    _locale = null;
    notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Just if anyone is facing the same problem.
Thank you all very much for the highly appreciated support. Kind regards